# How to adjust UINavigationBar's text and buttons when you change tintColor?

Tags: iphone

I was able to change the tintColor of the UINavigationBar by doing:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

However the problem is when the color gets too light, the button, backButton and the title text is not visible. Why is it that it doesn't automatically adjust itself based on the tint color? Do I have to create custom button, custom title view and custom back button if I change the tint color?

[alt text http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/9617/picture1tlv.png](http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/9617/picture1tlv.png)

Comment: the screenshot shows the nav bar with a white background. Is this what you saw when setting red as the tint color!?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite annoying.  You will need to manipulate the custom views of [`navigationBar.titleView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView), and the [`barbuttonitem.customView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarButtonItem/customView).  There you can use a `UILabel` with text of the desired background color.  I don't think there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: that doesn't work for the back button. You can't have a custom view on top of that arrow.

Comment: You can mock one in photoshop and use it as a subview.  Personally I think you are better off not having tintColor be very light.